# Angular 2 Design for nested Data

Tags: angular, nested

I currently develop a planning board for teams to plan their sprints in one iteration. In advance this is my first Angular 2 application and also my first web app. So the focus of this question is, to figure out what the best way of designing an Angular 2 App, with nested data, is.

**Structure of the current Application**
In the backend runs a ASP.NET Web API to provide the data. The data structure is constructed as follows:
The top layer consists of the planning boards for each iteration. These boards consits of teams, which in turn have sprints. (Team x have 4 Sprints in this iteration and team y 6). You can CRUD features in the sprints.

How to map this in Angular 2?

**Approaches**
My first and only approach until now was to create a component for each layer, which should manage the respective content. That means I have a component
- for the planning boards, which should load the teams for the selected board,
- for the teams, which should load and sort the sprints for the teams,
- for the sprints which load, sort and manage the features in the sprints.

My first problem with this approach is to create the right HTML structure or even to know if the plannend structure works in the end. Currently I creat following template:

```
    <planningboard>
     <team class="Team-Yellow">
     </team>
     <team class="Team-Blue">
     </team>
     ...
    </planningboard>
```

At this point I'm also able to nest sprint tags under the team tags by selecting the team tags in the teams component. But only for each team tag the same sprint tags, because I'm not able to filter the selctor with the HTML class attribute to choose only the sprints which belongs to the teams. This problem has made me questionable wether I am pursuing a feasible solution at all?

1. Is it a good or even a working approach in this context to create HTML Tags for each relevant entity of my data-model?

   - One planningboard-tag for the whole board
   - X team-tags for the teams
   - Y sprint-tags nested under the single team-tags
   - Z feature-tags nested under the sprint-tags
2. Is it good to have only one component for each entity type in this context?

   - One for planninboards
   - One for teams
   - One for sprints
   - One for features

Edit:

In the meantime I tried another approach. I just use one component which gets all data and creats the HTML template out of it. The HTML looks like this:

```
<planningboard>
    <div class="Team-Yellow">
      <div class="Sprint-1>
        <ul class="Features">
        <li>Feature 1</li>
        ...
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="Sprint-2">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Team-X">
    ...
    </div>
</planningboard>
```

But with this approach I have only one component which is responsible for the content and which manages all data. I'm also not sure if this is a good idea.

**Edit: In relation to the comment from Günter Zöchbauer.**

Maybe I have a reason for less or even more then one component for an entity type. Currently I create "angular-tags" for each entity in one component. As an example I have the team component, which manages around 50-60 sprint-tags, because I create sprint-tags for each team. In every tutorial I've made and ervery angular code I've seen yet, nobody handles or even creates more then one same tag for a component. But if I do not, my HTML structure makes no sense. So what can I do? Create dynamically for each entity a component or just create one component?
Also I meet some concrete problems:

1. How to differentiate between the different tags or filter the selector (with HTML class/id)? So that the component is able to assign the right values,

Example:
The planningboard component is responsible for assigning teams to a board. Therefore it gets the right team data, after selecting a board and then builds the following HTML template:

```
<planningboard id="PI 17.1">
 <team class="Team-Yellow">
 </team>
 <team class="Team-XY">
 </team>
 ...
</planningboard>
```

No problems until here.
Now the team component should insert the sprints into the team tags. Therefore it gets the relevant sprint data and knows the teams. But how to insert the right HTML structure? Should I insert a HTML template wich is able to iterate over the sprints and compare their team-id with the parents team-ids?
That's the reason for my second approach, mentioned above with only one component. In one component I just can say, creat for every Team a team container and in this container for every sprint a sprint container, and so on. But if I do this with a compnent for each entity type, I always need to iterate over the existing structure of the parent element and then pass in the child tags. And I don't know how.

I'm grateful for any advice or tip!

Greetings,
Hendrik

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you mean by "Is it a good or even a working approach to create the HTML Tags out of the Model?"

Comment: "Is it good to have only one component for each Data Layer in this context?" Usually it's better to have fine-grained components that do exactly one thing and to it well. Not exactly sure what "Data Layer" means here exactly.

Comment: Tanks for your comments, I will update the questions.

Comment: It's still difficult to me to grasp what the question is about. You can have a component per planningboard, teams, sprints, features, and each of this components can be built from several other components. What might be an argument for more than one component for an entity type? How different are instances of an entity type?

Comment: The instances of an entity type are not really different and I don't know any argument for having more then one component for an entity type. The

Comment: Then there probably is none ;-)

Comment: Maybe I have a reason. I updated the question.